# Do 1 Thess. 4:16-17 (coming of the Lord in the air with His "caught up" saints) & Rev 6:9-11 (during the 5th seal) describe the same event?

Tags: revelation, chronology, resurrection, 1-thessalonians, second-coming

From 1 Thess. 4:

> 16 For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, with
> the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the dead in
> Christ shall rise first:
>
> 17 Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with
> them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever
> be with the Lord.

From Rev 6:

> 9 When He opened the fifth seal, I saw under the altar the souls of
> those who had been slain for the word of God and for the testimony
> which they held.
>
> ...
>
> 11 Then a white robe was given to each of them...

Are these passages both describing the same event?

---

Note this would make both prior to the sixth seal (Rev 6:12)

Comment: I edited the question in response to the vote to close it; if you don't like the changes or feel that they defeat the original intent of the question, I can roll them back.

Comment: I think we should be suspicious of this suggestion because it is difficult to associate "souls under the altar" with "in the air".  Why should/might they be the same thing?

Comment: Dottard - "Dead in Christ" equates to "souls of those who had been slain for the word of God and for the testimony which they held".

Comment: I mean, that's supposed to be all believers - dead to the world, hid with God, taking on the mind of Christ and thus headless (missing their own minds), and dressed in white. But you will get a ton of revelation interpretation and has that ever been useful to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first declare myself that I don't believe in the Rapture. So I am not going to use any kind of Rapture theory in my answer. I just analyse it literally by its word.

1 Thessalonians 4:15-17 Paul wrote that the dead in Christ will rise first before the living will see the Lord or Christ, whereas Revelation 6:11 wrote the souls under the altar were told to wait a little longer, until the full number of their fellow servants, their brothers and sisters, were killed just as they had been. So the souls under the altar had not yet been risen. It leads to my conclusion that **they are not describing the same event**.

The first resurrection is seen in Revelation 20:5, before the millennium as they will reign with the Christ for a thousand years (Revelation 20:6). There is no further description about the living people in the millennium. So 1 Thessalonians 4:17 does not have a parallel verse in the Bible to compare.

Comment: Vincent - Rev 6:10 "How long ... until you judge ... 11 Then a white robe was given to each of them ..." I suggest that these souls "who had been slain for the word of God" Rev 6:9 are dead church believers already in Heaven that become part of the "great multitude" Rev 7:9 "standing before the throne and before the Lamb clothed in white robs with palm branches in their hands.

Comment: @Hank - Rev 7:14 told us the people in Rev 7:9 were coming out of the great tribulation. So they were dead in the tribulation, whereas Rev 6:9 are dead church believers as you said, and those were dead since the early church. So they belonged to different periods, but were amongst in the 1st resurrection (Rev 20:4)

Comment: Vincent - Rev 7:14 "coming (2064) out (1537) of" Note - erchomai (2064) followed by ek (1537), from or out of the Tribulation Rev.7:14 "having escaped from {a.t.}". Also, Rev 3:10 "I will also keep you from the hour of trial." I suggest that these are the "caught up" "great multitude" brought by the Lord to His Father 1Th 3:13. Ref NKJV, Interlinear, The Complete WordStudy Dictionary New Testament, ISBN 0-89957-663-X –